# Forward vs reverse mode differentiation - Pytorch

Tags: numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, backpropagation

In the first example of [Learning PyTorch with Examples](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html), the author demonstrates how to create a neural network with numpy. Their code is pasted below for convenience:

```
# from: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = np.random.randn(N, D_in)
y = np.random.randn(N, D_out)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = np.random.randn(D_in, H)
w2 = np.random.randn(H, D_out)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.dot(w1)
    h_relu = np.maximum(h, 0)
    y_pred = h_relu.dot(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = np.square(y_pred - y).sum()
    print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.T.dot(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.dot(w2.T)
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.copy()
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0
    grad_w1 = x.T.dot(grad_h)

    # Update weights
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

What is confusing to me is why gradients of w1 and w2 are computed **with respect to loss** (2nd to last code block).

Normally the opposite computation happens: the gradients of loss is computed with respect to the weights, as quoted here:

- "When training neural networks, we think of the cost (a value describing how bad a neural network performs) as a function of the parameters (numbers describing how the network behaves). **We want to calculate the derivatives of the cost with respect to all the parameters, for use in gradient descent**. Now, there’s often millions, or even tens of millions of parameters in a neural network. So, reverse-mode differentiation, called backpropagation in the context of neural networks, gives us a massive speed up!" ([Colah's blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Backprop/)).

So my question is: why is the derivation computation in the example above in reverse order as compared to normal back propagation computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a typo in the comment. They are actually computing gradient of `loss` w.r.t. `w2` and `w1`.

Let's quickly derive the gradient of `loss` w.r.t. `w2` just to be sure. By inspection of your code we have

[image]

Using the chain rule from calculus

[image].

Each term can be represented using the basic rules of matrix calculus. These turn out to be

[image]

and

[image].

Plugging these terms back into the initial equation we get

[image].

Which perfectly matches the expressions described by

```
grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)       # gradient of loss w.r.t. y_pred
grad_w2 = h_relu.T.dot(grad_y_pred)    # gradient of loss w.r.t. w2
```

in the back-propagation code you provided.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why `h_relu` is being used to get the "gradient of loss w.r.t. w2" when `w2` comes BEFORE `h_relu` when you are going backwards.

Comment: the gradient of y w.r.t w_2 is exactly the relu activations for that layer. This means that you need to hold onto those activations for backprop.

Comment: If you look at the expression used to represent y_pred then it should be clear that dy/dw2 = relu(h)

Comment: Thank you for instant response from answer from over a year ago. My understanding was that `h_relu` is the just Relu applied to the layer before it. Which would be `w1` in this case. I thought `w2` was derived from `h_relu` and `w1`.

Comment: I know it's not this simple, but my analogy would be 2+3=5. 5-1 = 4. 4+7 = 13 and trying to get back to two by skipping 7 and starting with 4. Sorry, I don't know how else to put it. Why is `w2` used to compute the gradient for `h_relu` in the next line? To me, this looks like things are happening in their proper order, but loss computed with the h_relu to get the gradients for w2 does not.

Comment: @Renoldus I don't know if I totally understand the issue, but I think what you're saying is that since relu is applied before w2 then you would expect the back-propagation to not require the output of relu to compute the gradient of loss w.r.t w2? It's actually because this assumption is simply false (if you follow the math) that in order to perform back-propagation you actually need to save every activation from every layer during forward pass.

Comment: @Renoldus Perhaps this will help. Consider the expression `y = relu(h) * w2`. For the sake of simplicity suppose that `h` and `w2` are scalars. Now suppose we want to compute `dy/dw2`. Since we know that `relu(h)` was computed before `w2` was used then it follows that `relu(h)` is independent of `w2`. Therefore we can treat `relu(h)` as a constant. This results in `dy/dw2 = relu(h)`. Notice that it's exactly opposite of your argument. It's really because of the fact that `relu(h)` is used before `w2` that it is required to compute the gradient w.r.t. `w2`.

Comment: I know that points me in the right direction although it is still fuzzy. I guess I didn't know what a derivative is. I always figured Pytorch had some kind of derivative algorithm going behind the scenes and actually didn't quite understand how this was doing what Pytorch does exactly. (Though I thought it went in a certain straight order). I watched weeks of videos on taking derivatives and it always involved rules like taking the power down from x, putting it in front, and factoring equations. I know what a derivative is mostly, but I guess not so much.

Comment: I'll try to ask a more direct question if you will indulge me. I thought the gradient went all the way back to other gradients. How come `grad_w2 = h_relu.T.dot(grad_y_pred)` is only subtracted from `w2` and it is not used to find the next backward gradient?

Comment: @Renoldus I added an answer to your original question, hopefully this resolves your confusion.