# Is this Neural Net example I'm looking at a mistake or am I not understanding backprop?

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch

Is this model using one relu in two places, or are gradients computed by doing a matrix multiplication of layers on both sides of one layer?

In the last layer of this simple neural net (below) during back prop it calculates the gradient for the last layer `w2` by doing a matrix multiplication of y prediction - y and `h_relu`, which I thought was only **between** layers `w1` and `w2` not between `w2` and `y_pred`

The line in question is near the bottom. It is `grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)`.
I am confused because I thought everything was supposed to go in order forward and go in order backwards. Is this relu being used in two places?

Here is an attempt at a visual illustration of the model.

[image]

This example is from the [Pytorch website](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html). It is the second block of code on the page.

```
grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)


import torch

dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device("cpu")
# device = torch.device("cuda:0") # Uncomment this to run on GPU

# N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
# H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

# Create random input and output data
x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

# Randomly initialize weights
w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

learning_rate = 1e-6
for t in range(500):
    # Forward pass: compute predicted y
    h = x.mm(w1)
    h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
    y_pred = h_relu.mm(w2)

    # Compute and print loss
    loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum().item()
    if t % 100 == 99:
        print(t, loss)

    # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
    grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
    grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
    grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
    grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
    grad_h[h < 0] = 0
    grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)

    # Update weights using gradient descent
    w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
    w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

I appreciate your patience looking at this and trying to clear this up for me.
If you can try adding another layer of whieghts in the middle with another relu that might help me understand. This is what I was trying to do.

Comment: This is a similar question for the same network (looking at the numpy version) but the math is the same. Let me know if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886606/forward-vs-reverse-mode-differentiation-pytorch

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why `h_relu` is being used to get the "gradient of loss w.r.t. w2" when `w2` comes BEFORE `h_relu` when you are going backwards. I guess my assumptions about what exactly back prop is have been wrong because things seem to be happening out of order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following diagram which represents the network in question. The concept of back-propagation is simply a way to quickly and intuitively apply the chain rule on a complex sequence of operations to compute the gradient of an output w.r.t. a tensor. Usually we are interested in computing the gradients of **leaf tensors** (tensors which are not derived from other tensors) with respect to a loss or objective. All the leaf tensors are represented as circles in the following diagram and the loss is represented by the rectangle with the L label.

[image]

Using the backward diagram we can follow the path from L to w1 and w2 in order to determine which partial derivatives we need in order to compute the gradient of L w.r.t. w1 and w2. For simplicity we will assume that all the leaf tensors are scalars so as to avoid getting into the complexities of multiplying vectors and matrices.

Using this approach the gradients of L w.r.t. w1 and w2 are

[image]

and

[image]

Something to notice is that since w2 is a leaf tensor, we only use dy/dw2 (aka `grad_w2`) during computation of dL/dw2 since it isn't part of the path from L to w1.

Comment: Thank you. This is above and beyond. Can you say anything to explain why there is a "leaf tensor" here? A neural network is functions inside functions that alternate from linear to non-linear if I'm not mistaken. Why would a "simple example" nn have one of its linear layers be slightly adjacent(?) to the model? A kind of branch off inside of the model. I thought things like this were only typical in RNNs or other exotic architectures.

Comment: Recurrant networks are different. Generally you can think of a recurrant network as kind of having a feedback loop, i.e. the output of a layer is passed back into the input of an earlier layer. In this case the network is purely feedforward. The way the diagrams are often depicted kind of hides the fact that leaf tensors are present thoughout the network (usually encapsulated with a layer). In fact all trainable weights are leaf tensors.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding why the gradient for `w2` uses a layer that came before it to find its derivative but the gradient for the relu (`h_relu`) uses two things that came after it to find its derivative with `grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())`. I don't mean to nitpick and hope I'm not being annoying, but `grad_h_relu` comes from `w2` and I don't think your illustration shows a derivative coming from `w2`. I also don't understand why the input data `x` has a derivative pointing to it because the model should not be "acting on" the input data, right?

Comment: So consider the expression z = x * y. The derivative of z w.r.t. y is dz/dy = x, even though x "came before" z it is still needed to compute the derivative of z w.r.t. y. The point of the diagram and backpropagation isn't anything like "run the network backwards" as some people seem to think. It simply defines how the gradient may be computed by describing which partials are needed in order to compute the desired gradient. It doesn't say anything about which values can and cannot be part of the calculation. That would be a result of the rules of differentiation from calculus.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that the loss is impacted by every single leaf tensor in the network, therefore the gradient of loss w.r.t. any leaf tensor will likely be a function of every other leaf tensor. In this framework it shouldn't be surprising to see h_relu in the gradient computation for dL/dw2 despite the fact that w2 isn't defined by the result of h_relu. Again, we are computing the derivative of loss w.r.t. w2 and loss is affected by h_relu.

Comment: "backpropagation isn't anything like "run the network backwards" as some people seem to think." I am confused to see the derivatives are computed just by doing a matrix multiplication. In some examples you showed the derivative equals the constant in the equation, which might wrongly lead me to believe you could just pluck out whatever the constant was instead of doing a transpose and multiplying. In videos of vector derivatives I don't think I've ever seen derivatives calculated by doing a transpose and matrix multiplication.

Comment: In your example a few comments ago you wrote dz/dy = x. Did you mean dz/dy x = (something)?

Comment: No I meant dz/dy = x. To be honest I think you're missing some fundamental pre-requisites to understand backpropagation fully. I'm not sure what your motivation is exactly but I think spending too much time on these details is kind of missing the point. One of the strengths of frameworks like pytorch and tensorflow are that you don't need to understand the details of the calculus or back-propagation for the vast majority of standard use cases thanks to autograd. Instead of stressing yourself out it may be more effective to just trust that `loss.backward()` computes the gradient correctly.

Comment: And to be clear I don't mean anything negative by that last comment. I think it's great that people are interested in really digging into the details. I'm quite confident that if you had completed semester long courses in multivariate calculus and linear algbera then you wouldn't have nearly as much confusion. As it stands I think the problem is that you're "drinking from a firehose" so to speak. In my experience trying to learn too many new concepts at the same time or trying to learn too quickly just results in more stress and confusion.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn what exactly is happening. I'm sure it is something exact, so it isn't unkowable. I have consumed months worth of videos, years worth maybe. They all give a generalized (rarely specific) view of what is happening. I hate to rant about it, because it is useless, but I just watched 3blue1brown's video on backprop for about the 4th time and he isn't multiplying any matrices or talking of leaf tensors. All the multivariable videos I've seen seem to take the derivative for each element one by one in the vector, though videos tend to go in one ear and out the other.

Comment: I made the first post you so graciously commented on because I was trying to add a layer of weights and relu to the example code. I asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62272830/i-modified-a-few-layers-to-an-example-of-a-neural-network-just-to-see-if-i-could/62273432#62273432) today. What do you think of the answer? Talking to you got me close to getting it done. I just about understand the code at a level high enough to work with now. I'll take a look at derivatives of matrices the next few days. My stress comes from the isolation/ not being able to convey context of prob

Comment: 3Blue1Brown was writing derivatives dy/dx(x)=(something). I'm totally confused how y hat minus y is called a gradient, how the constant in something multiplied in the forward pass is called a gradient, and how multiplication of transposed matrices can also produce something called a gradient. Or are some of these derivatives or partial derivatives but also gradients because of special properties? It is a firehose.