# I modified a few layers to an example of a neural network just to see if I could. What's wrong with it?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

A simple neural network I found had the layers w1, Relu, and w2. I tried to add a new weight layer in the middle and a second Relu after it. So, the layers are as follows w1, Relu, w_mid, Relu, and w2.
It is much much slower than the original 3 layer network if it works at all. I'm not sure if everything is getting a forward pass and if back prop is working across every part it is supposed to.
The neural network is from [this link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html). It is the third block of code down the page.

This is the code I changed.
Below it is the original.

```
    import torch
    dtype = torch.float
    device = torch.device("cpu")
    #device = torch.device("cuda:0") # Uncomment this to run on GPU

    # N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
    # H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
    N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 250, 250, 10

    # Create random input and output data
    x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
    y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

    # Randomly initialize weights
    w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
    w_mid = torch.randn(H, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
    w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

    learning_rate = 1e-5
    for t in range(5000):
        # Forward pass: compute predicted y
        h = x.mm(w1)
        h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
        k = h_relu.mm(w_mid)
        k_relu = k.clamp(min=0)
        y_pred = k_relu.mm(w2)


        # Compute and print loss
        loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum().item()
        if t % 1000 == 0:
            print(t, loss)

        # Backprop to compute gradients of w1, mid, and w2 with respect to loss
        grad_y_pred = (y_pred - y) * 2
        grad_w2 = k_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
        grad_k_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
        grad_k = grad_k_relu.clone()
        grad_k[k < 0] = 0
        grad_mid = h_relu.t().mm(grad_k)
        grad_h_relu = grad_k.mm(w1.t())
        grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
        grad_h[h < 0] = 0
        grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)

        # Update weights
        w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
        w_mid -= learning_rate * grad_mid
        w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

The loss is ..
0 1904074240.0
1000 639.4848022460938
2000 639.4848022460938
3000 639.4848022460938
4000 639.4848022460938

This is the original code from the Pytorch website.

```
    import torch


    dtype = torch.float
    #device = torch.device("cpu")
    device = torch.device("cuda:0") # Uncomment this to run on GPU

    # N is batch size; D_in is input dimension;
    # H is hidden dimension; D_out is output dimension.
    N, D_in, H, D_out = 64, 1000, 100, 10

    # Create random input and output data
    x = torch.randn(N, D_in, device=device, dtype=dtype)
    y = torch.randn(N, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

    # Randomly initialize weights
    w1 = torch.randn(D_in, H, device=device, dtype=dtype)
    w2 = torch.randn(H, D_out, device=device, dtype=dtype)

    learning_rate = 1e-6
    for t in range(500):
        # Forward pass: compute predicted y
        h = x.mm(w1)
        h_relu = h.clamp(min=0)
        y_pred = h_relu.mm(w2)

        # Compute and print loss
        loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum().item()
        if t % 100 == 99:
            print(t, loss)

        # Backprop to compute gradients of w1 and w2 with respect to loss
        grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y)
        grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred)
        grad_h_relu = grad_y_pred.mm(w2.t())
        grad_h = grad_h_relu.clone()
        grad_h[h < 0] = 0
        grad_w1 = x.t().mm(grad_h)

        # Update weights using gradient descent
        w1 -= learning_rate * grad_w1
        w2 -= learning_rate * grad_w2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations for the gradient of `h_relu` is not correct.

```py
grad_h_relu = grad_k.mm(w1.t())
```

That should be a `w_mid` not `w1`:

```py
grad_h_relu = grad_k.mm(w_mid.t())
```

Other than that, the calculations are correct, but you should lower the learning rate, as the gradients are very big at the beginning, making the weights very large and that leads to overflowing values (infinity), which in turn produce NaN losses and gradients. This is known as *exploding gradients*.

In your example a learning rate of `1e-8` seems to work.

Comment: Thank you. You say "gradients are very big at the beginning". My modified network needs a lower learning rate. Does a bigger network have bigger gradients?

Comment: Bigger networks have the potential to have much larger gradients, because for each matrix multiplication the gradients are amplified (large gradients get even larger). In your case, a significant factor is the loss function, the sum of the squared errors, which gets large fairly quickly. In practice, you would use losses with smaller magnitudes, such as the mean squared error, which mitigate some of the risks.

Comment: Thanks. Before this I thought a 'gradient' was a derivative, or partial derivative. I didn't know y hat minus y was a 'gradient'. I also didn't know you could do matrix multiplication to get a derivative. Gradients in question... `grad_y_pred = 2.0 * (y_pred - y),  grad_w2 = h_relu.t().mm(grad_y_pred),  grad_h_relu`

Comment: Gradients are the partial derivatives. The derivative of *(x - y)²* with respect to *x* is *2(x - y)*. The others follow from the chain rule. It's called *reverse mode differentiation* (or backpropagation). [Calculus on Computational Graphs: Backpropagation](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Backprop/) has some good explanations for that.